# Possible Ways to Communicate Between iFrame and Parent Page across domains

Tags: javascript, iframe, triggers, cross-domain

Please suggest possible techniques to trigger events in parent page from an iFrame. I tried out url Hashing and using window.postMessage techniques but without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easyXDM is designed for this exact purpose.
You can find it at http://easyxdm.net and it has quite a few examples.

To sum it up, it allows two windows to communicate 'freely' using either strings or RPC calls.

See http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/methods.html for one of the RPC-demos.

Comment: By the way, feel free to contact me if you have an problems using it (I'm the author).

Answer (score 2):

No success because you cannot for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The modern answer to this question is the new cross-document messaging (Web Messaging API)

See Opera's introduction here:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/window-postmessage-messagechannel/

Or the specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/

Answer (score 1):

The only idea that comes to mind is to have a script on server side that the iFrame sends its events to (combined with a unique ID) and that the parent page can poll (either through a server script on its domain, or JSONP). That's a lot of work to do, though, and requires cooperation from both the parent page and the iframe.