# How to have content pop out of iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, drop-down-menu, overflow

Say I have a menu which is initially 200px by 100px. I need to include it in an iframe but the problem is it is a dropdown menu and when it opens the menu gets cut of since it is inside the frame. Is there a way to have it drop out of the frame?

Comment: If the menu is of your own design, then what's it doing inside an iframe?  Seems like you could just get rid of the iframe to solve your issue.

Comment: It almost sounds like you might be looking for framesets rather than iframes...  I'd try to avoid both if you can though.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. Anyways, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

If both the parent page and the page within your iframe are coming from the same domain, you can communicate between them via JS:

[Possible Ways to Communicate Between iFrame and Parent Page across domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771397/possible-ways-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-parent-page-across-domains)

The solution would be to, upon hover, send JS to the parent page and have the parent page then render the menu on top of the iframe.

That said, having to use a menu within an iframe that then pops out of the iframe seems to be not a technical problem as much as it is a visual design and layout problem.

Comment: good idea. what i was thinking was:
on hover, tell the parent to increase the frame height and allowtransparency="true". 
then on mouse out back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. You will need to use a different approach, such as downloading the content of the frame on the server and inlining it in the parent page instead. Another possibility would be to float the parent page's content over the iframe and make the iframe larger.