# Pass values between two websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, session

Is it possible to pass values between two completely different websites?

I have website A that is embedded in an Iframe in website B. User logs into website B using email id and I need to pass that email id to the iframe/website A. Can I do this using session variables. I know of webservices solution, but that seems too big a method to just pass one value to display. Thanks any insight, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the `emailId` to the `iframe` via URL, like so:

```
<iframe src="http://website.com/somepage.aspx?i=emailId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go the webservice route, but this may work for you too:

[Possible Ways to Communicate Between iFrame and Parent Page across domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771397/possible-ways-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-parent-page-across-domains)